# MS-SQL updating a column in a table from a counter, resetting count on company name change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

First time poster, tried to search and follow board etiquette.

I have a table for purchase order line data. Simplified it looks like this:
`po_no`, `warehouse_name`, `vendor`, `item_no`, `qty`, `price`, `eta_date`, `spare_numeric_field`

I need to go through the table and update the `spare_numeric_field` from a counter for each instance of `warehouse_name`, `vendor`, `item_no`. On change the counter needs to reset and begin numbering the next instance of `warehouse_name`, `vendor`, `item_no`.

There are an undetermined number of purchase orders, one vendor may have one instance of `warehouse_name`, `vendor`, `item_no` and another popular vendor may have 100+ purchase orders.

Fortunately I had a test database to work with and have managed to successfully sequentially number all the purchase order lines. Any suggestions on how to perform the above scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide sample data and your expected result?

Comment: 123, lax, vendor1, item1, 10, 25.00, 01/01/2015, 1     124, hou, vendor2, item2, 1, 5, 01/01/2015, 1    125, lax, vendor1, item3, 1, 10.00, 02/01/2015, 1        126, lax, vendor1, item1, 10, 25.00, 02/01/2015, 2     Sorry, could not do a crlf but in the above example see the spare numeric field on po number 123 and 126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
SELECT
    po_no, 
    warehouse_name, 
    vendor, 
    item_no, 
    qty, 
    price, 
    eta_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY
            warehouse_name, vendor, item no
        ORDER BY
            warehouse_name
    ) spare_numeric_field
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thanks mxix, that works perfect for a select.  Now how would I modify that to update the spare_numeric_field?  <br/> 1482 WHS Bay Area Systems                                   02474 CONE                                         1.0000 15.0000 2012-11-15 00:00:00.000 1 <br/>
1483 WHS Bay Area Systems                                   02474 CONE                                         1.0000 15.0000 2012-11-15 00:00:00.000 2 <br/>
2273 WHS Coastal Hard Drives                                0111A                                              5.0000 10.0000 2013-07-05 00:00:00.000 1 <br/>

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, trying to get the board options down.

Comment: With the help from mxix I think I have it. Need to get a better handle on this and how to use the board.      with TEST
as
(
select *
, row_number() over(PARTITION BY
            loc, company, item_no ORDER BY
            loc ) as rnk
from poline
)
update TEST
set N14_4_4 = rnk
WHERE TEST.STATUS = 'O'
go

Comment: If someone would dial me a clue and point me at how to post the sql statement cleanly, I will post it for future readers.